# Check if the User is valid user on Domain - Active Directory

Tags: c#, asp.net, active-directory

A lot of people posted about this but could not get anything to work. I am trying to get the user's username and password on an Asp.net form (the same username and password which the user uses to login to their computer on a domain).

I am using the [PrincipalContext](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.accountmanagement.principalcontext(v=vs.110).aspx) to validate the user.

[image]

Although I provide valid username and password, but `pc.ValidateCredentials` always returns false.

This is the first time I am doing User Authentication through Active Directory and have no idea what else do I require to successfully validate a user from Active Directory.

Do I need to provide information in the Container and Name properties on the PrincipalContext Object as it appears to be null.

[image]

Currently I am running this code from local machine which is on domain.

Comment: Maybe you have to prefix the domain to username, i.e. `"DOMAIN\\" + txtUsername.Text.Trim()`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do you have the correct domain? Maybe it is called different than 'DOMAIN', try this one:

```
  private bool Authenticate(string user, string password)
  {
        using ( var context = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, Environment.UserDomainName) ) {
           return context.ValidateCredentials(user.Trim(), password.Trim());
        }
  }
```

Comment: Actually the domain name is "DOMAIN". Environment.UserDomain also returned the same. Didn't work, same results

Comment: This is weird. Your method actually worked. I tried to put my email address abc.xyz@example.com instead of the username. It validated my credentials but my actual email is abc.xyz-e@example.com. What am I missing.

Comment: Try `var me = Principal.FindByIdentity(new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain), WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().User.Value);` and check properties like `Name`, `SamAccountName`, `UserPrincipalName`, etc. if you see any difference.

Answer (score 0):

Please use below function

```
private bool AuthenticateAD(string userName, string password, string domain, out string message)
{

    message = "";       

    DirectoryEntry entry = new
        DirectoryEntry("LDAP://" + domain, userName, password);
    try
    {
        object obj = entry.NativeObject;
        DirectorySearcher search = new DirectorySearcher(entry);
        search.Filter = "(SAMAccountName=" + userName + ")";
        search.PropertiesToLoad.Add("cn");
        SearchResult result = search.FindOne();
        if (null == result)
        {
            return false;
        }           

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        message = ex.Message;
        return false;
        //throw new Exception("Error authenticating user. " + ex.Message);
    }

    return true;
}
```

Comment: In the message I get "Logon failure: unknown user name or bad password.". I am using the same username and password through which I login to the computer.